# converting a Perl regex to python

Tags: python, regex, perl

Im converting some Perl code to python, and I have a regex that works perfectly in Perl, but does not work when I copy it into `re.match`. The Perl line is:

```
if !(/(\s\{\s0x[0-9A-Fa-f]*, 0x[0-9A-Fa-f]*, .*\}.*)|(.* reservations for core .*)|(.* reservedMemoryAreas.*)/)
```

and my translation to python is:

```
if re.match('(\s\{\s0x[0-9A-Fa-f]*, 0x[0-9A-Fa-f]*, .*\}.*)|(.* reservations for core .*)|(.* reservedMemoryAreas.*)',line)is None:
```

as you can see I copy pasted the regex into `re`, excluding the enclosing `/`. however for this line the Perl regex matches, but the python one dosent:

```
  { 0x0000000097747E80, 0x40, 1, 0x0, 1, 0x0, 1, 0x0, 0, 0x0, 1, 0, "Res[0]" }, // Res[0]
```

Is the regex syntax supposed to be exactly the same?
Can anyone help me out here?
Thanks

Comment: Found the problem - I used `re.match` which searches at the beginning of a string, while Perl defaults to `re.search` that searches the whole string. Ill leave this around in case anyone ever finds this useful.

Comment: Then post it as an answer. As a side note, I don't see why you sometimes use a literal space or `\s` ...

Comment: @HamZa ok, I will post it, It just seemed like I dident really earn the rep... as for the `\s`, this is a bunch of legacy code, which I strongly prefer to touch as less as possible..

Comment: Note: You probably want to use a raw string in Python to represent your regex. Just stick an `r` in front of the string, like so: `r'(\s\{\s0...`. It'll save you the headache of trying to use `\b` and tearing your hair out wondering why it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get a match in Python as well using your pattern.

```
import re

string = ' { 0x0000000097747E80, 0x40, 1, 0x0, 1, 0x0, 1, 0x0, 0, 0x0, 1, 0, "Res[0]" }, // Res[0]'
pattern = '(\s\{\s0x[0-9A-Fa-f]*, 0x[0-9A-Fa-f]*, .*\}.*)|(.* reservations for core .*)|(.* reservedMemoryAreas.*)'

if re.match(pattern, string):
    print "Found match."
else:
    print "No match."

>>> python test.py
>>> Found match.
```

Another thing: You don't need to use `if ... is None:`, you can just use

```
if regex(pattern, string):
```

Python uses implicit booleans a lot. So in a boolean context `None` evaluates to `False`

You might try using `\s+` instead of just `\s` at the beginning and see if that works. When I copied the test string to my editor I accidentaly copied it with two leading spaces instead of one, which of course the pattern would not match since it only checks for exactly one.

Comment: ah, It must be due to white spaces at the beginning than.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem - I used `re.match` which searches at the beginning of a string, while Perl defaults to `re.search` that searches the whole string. Ill leave this around in case anyone ever finds this useful.